# GKE Firestore 403 PermissionDenied error with a Kubernetes service account

Tags: python, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-kubernetes-engine

So we have a Kubernetes cluster setup (with namespace dev) in GCP, which has some nodes, and one of those nodes has a pod running which runs a python application in a docker container. The Kubernetes cluster has a Kubernetes default service account associated with it.

Now we recently setup a Firestore database and wanted our python application to connect with it.
We made sure that our default Kubernetes service account has the required permissions enabled:

```
kubectl create rolebinding default-firestore-agent \
  --clusterrole=firestore.serviceAgent \
  --serviceaccount=dev:default \
  --namespace=dev
  
kubectl create rolebinding default-datastore-user \
  --clusterrole=datastore.user \
  --serviceaccount=dev:default \
  --namespace=dev
```

After running these above commands, we get confirmation messages that the rolebindings have been created. However when we try to connect to Firestore from within the python application, we get a `PermissionDenied` error with the following stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/document.py", line 167, in set
    write_results = batch.commit(**kwargs)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/batch.py", line 59, in commit
    commit_response = self._client._firestore_api.commit(
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/services/firestore/client.py", line 1125, in commit
    response = rpc(
               ^^^^
  File "/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 113, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 349, in retry_wrapped_func
    return retry_target(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 191, in retry_target
    return target()
           ^^^^^^^^
  File "/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/timeout.py", line 120, in func_with_timeout
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 74, in error_remapped_callable
    raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc
google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 Request had insufficient authentication scopes. [reason: "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT"
domain: "googleapis.com"
metadata {
  key: "service"
  value: "firestore.googleapis.com"
}
metadata {
  key: "method"
  value: "google.firestore.v1.Firestore.Commit"
}
]
```

If it helps, this is the code that we're using to connect to Firestore:

```
from google.cloud import firestore
db = firestore.Client()
doc_ref = db.collection("users").document("alovelace")
doc_ref.set({"first": "Ada", "last": "Lovelace", "born": 1815})
```

We're not sure what we're doing wrong, this should work because the associated service account has all the required permissions to access Firestore. Also, we don't want to store credentials in a JSON file and use it to connect to Firestore.

Any pointers on what we're doing wrong or any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Kubernetes (GKE) service accounts and RBAC are a parallel system to Google Cloud's service accounts and IAM. Unless, I'm missing a recent innovation, you **cannot** use Kubernetes RBAC to permit Google Cloud roles|permissions. Google provides a powerful solution to this problem, explained here [Use Workload Identity](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity) with GKE.